# Remove axis.text.x from ggplot graph based on specified condition

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm interested in customizing what axis.text.x appears on a graph. To make an example, I have the following code from iris.

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(flower = paste0(Species, " ", rn)) %>% 
  mutate(flower = fct_reorder(flower, Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(flower, Sepal.Length))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()
```

This will create a graph of each individual flower from the data in order of Sepal.length. I created a unique name of each flower by pasting the type with the rownumber of the data so the fct_reorder would do it's job.

But what if I only wanted the axis.text.x to show for those flowers which are from any type? Such as verginica? That's what I'm going for here. I'm guessing if you have a column to reference it might work but I'm struggling to find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the labels and breaks in the scale function:

**Original response**

```
iris_new <- iris %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(flower = paste0(Species, " ", rn)) %>% 
  mutate(flower = fct_reorder(flower, Sepal.Length),
         flowlabs = ifelse(grepl("virginica",flower),as.character(flower),""))  

iris_new %>% 
  ggplot(aes(flower, Sepal.Length))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = iris_new$flower, labels = iris_new$flowlabs)
```

**EDIT**
As mentioned by @stefan in the comments, better not to parse the data to the scale function. Answer revised with their much better response

```
iris_new %>% 
  ggplot(aes(flower, Sepal.Length))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ if_else(grepl("^virg", .x), .x, ""))
```

Note because you are not setting a label at every break point you need to define both breaks and labels, if you were just setting a new label for all breaks you could just define labels

Comment: There is no need to add a separate column. And as a general rule I would recommend to not pass data columns to breaks and labels. This might work for this example but is an error prone approach. Instead you could simply use a function, i.e. do `scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ if_else(grepl("^virg", .x), .x, ""))`

Comment: Ah thanks, I had tried a direct approach like this but tried calling the column name directly, didn't realise you needed to ~ .x. This is a much better method. I will adjust my post so people see who don't read the comments

Comment: So the problem (I think) with this solution is the grepl is going off what is mapped into the label which would be the x variable on the graph. I'm understanding that correctly right? If so, I was hoping to ref a diff column than what's being mapped on the x column.

Comment: @stefan Hopefully my comment above makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Sarah's original way worked for the data set I actually wanted to use it on without any errors. thanks all!

Comment: As you used the original, I have edited the answer to show both for future reference